# Error in my closure

Tags: javascript, closures

[JS Bin example](http://jsbin.com/sajajihe/1/edit)

Why does it not count, my output is always 1 in the console. I am new to closures and I must be missing something simple? Here is the code from the jsbin:

```
var counterFunc = function()
{
  var count = 0;

  var incCount = function()
  {
    count = count + 1;
    return count;
  };

  return incCount();
};

var myCounter = counterFunc;
console.log(myCounter());
console.log(myCounter());
```

Comment: please post a small, self-contained example here, not just a link to jsbin.

Comment: But FWIW, the answer is that you need to `return incCount`, not `return incCount();` - you should be returning the function itself, not the result of calling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By returning `incCount()` - the result of the invocation - from your `counterFunc`, you're not really creating a closure function. You want to *return a function*, and *invoke* the `counterFunc()` to create it:

```
var counterFunc = function() {
  var count = 0;

  var incCount = function() {
    count = count + 1;
    return count;
  };

  return incCount ;
//               ^
};

var myCounter = counterFunc();
//                         ^^
console.log(myCounter());
console.log(myCounter());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be returning the inner function itself, not the result of calling it

You therefore need to replace `return incCount()` with:

```
return incCount;
```

You subsequently need to directly invoke `counterFunc()` when you declare `myCounter`:

```
var myCounter = counterFunc();   //  myCounter is now the closure
```

Only then will `myCounter` be assigned a reference to the inner function, that happens to hold a "closure" over the local variable `count`.